# Class, subclass, abstract class, interface

Tags: java

How do you know whether to use/make a
class, a subclass, an abstract class, or
an interface?

I mean... a class like Math for example it´s not instantiated.
It´s a final class. There´s no IS-A relationship.

That is the purpose of making a class, a class that has no subclasses?

A subclass seems to be/have more specific code of its superclass.

An abstract class is something more generic, it can have implementations for its subclasses.

An interface is used/implemented in abstract classes and subclasses when those need to play a role.

Am I right?

Also..

A superclass is an abstract class?

Comment: You question doesn't make sense. Try to split it in different questions with more info.

Comment: Play class, subclass, abstract class, interface sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

In general

- interface - to group a related behaviors that can be added to an object.
- abstract class - when you need to create a base class with common states and behaviors that should not be instantiated
- class - to come up with an implementation
- subclasses - when you need some additional behaviors in an extensible class

Comment: Yes but a class like Math for example it can´t be extended.
When should I use/make such types of classes?

Comment: Those are final classes which cannot be extended. You create one if you don't want anybody to extend (or subclass) your class.

Comment: I mean, is Math a static class? And if yes, then that´s the only purpose of making a class (in the context that a dog class would be a subclass of animal for example, not a class in this context)

Comment: Whoever created that class didn't want anybody to extend that class so they defined it like `public final class Math ...`. There is no such thing as "static class". Members (e.g. method, field, ...) can be static, which means they belong to the class itself not to any instance of it.

Comment: What I´m trying to understand is: I make a class if I don´t want other class to extend it, because in the other way that would be an abstract class, right?

Comment: You have to make a class final if you don't want others to extend it. Abstract classes are the ones that you cannot instantiate.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was trying to understand basically whether to use a class, a subclass, an abstract class or/and an interface. 
A class that can be extended, wouldn´t be an abstract class?

Comment: An abstract class is the that one that you cannot create and object of, usually the purpose creating one would be extend it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a logical tree structure of classes. Then classes will be everything that is supposed to be directly used by other code, and subclasses will be more specific versions of parent-classes. Abstract classes will be parent-classes that isn't specific enough to be used in any way and interfaces will be abstractions of a type of classes, like a class but with no implementation at all. More or less...

That is the fast explanation. Clearly by asking a question like this you do not know the fundamentals of OOP so you should find a book to read about it, because nobody could explain all the related concepts in one post like this.

Answer (score 0):

`Class:` Every piece of code you write in java, is with in a class, so you consider class as a Data type, which describes what an object is and what it does.. (ie Instance variables and methods.)

`Sub-Class:` Usually needed when we want all the functionality of a certain class in our own class.

`Abstact-Class and Interface`: Now the reason why i tugged both of these together here, is because in Design Pattern Abstract class or an Interface is need to showcase a behaviour which keeps changing...